# Trigger Openshift job by ImageChange possible?

Tags: openshift

In openshift i have a regular job that needs to be run to set a specific configuration on an external server.
This configuration is specified by config files that can be found in another image that is generated by another build config.
After each build i manually delete the last job and recreate it again to update the configuration on another server.

So i would like to trigger the job automatically each time a new bc/image:latest is generated.

Is there a way to do this via trigger or post-commit?

I tried to set a trigger on my job by command `oc set triggers job/example --from-image=bc/image:latest`

The response is: `job/example does not support triggers`. I am using Openshift 4.11

Comment: How about using OpenShift Pipeline to built your own workflow?

Comment: @hiroyukik,  By "Openshift Pipeline", do you mean "Tekton"? I never heard about this tool before, but will have a look today. Thanks for your comment!